# Modelagem de dados - Relacionamento Opcional

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, entidade-relacionamento

Preciso fazer uma modelagem de banco de dados para o seguinte cenário:

Uma **Tarefa**(que é um ticket, uma solicitação de atendimento) terá sempre um **Endereço**, que é o local onde esta tarefa será atendida.
A **Tarefa** poderá ser aberta para atendimento em um **Imovel**(que seria um prédio por exemplo) que tem um endereço conhecido e previamente cadastrado no sistema, ou ela pode ser aberta para atendimento em um endereço qualquer, que será selecionado no momento da abertura da tarefa.

Nos casos onde a tarefa for aberta para atendimento em um imóvel, é necessário extrair em um relatório posteriormente os atendimentos relacionados a este imóvel.

Minha dúvida é como fazer este "relacionamento opcional" da tarefa para o imóvel de uma maneira correta. 
Pensei inicialmente em uma modelagem onde a ligação da Tarefa com o Endereço é feito através de uma tabela chamada TarefaEndereco, esta tabela teria uma chave estrangeira para Imovel e uma chave estrangeira para Endereço. 

Nos casos onde a tarefa fosse aberta para um Imóvel eu associaria o imóvel na tabela TarefaEndereco e pegaria o endereço do imóvel.

Nos casos onde a tarefa fosse aberta para um endereço qualquer eu associaria o Endereco na tabela TarefaEndereco e teria o endereco diretamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Poderiam me sugerir melhores formas de modelar este cenário específico de Tarefa para o seu Endereco sendo opcional o Imóvel.

Comment: Qual seria a diferença entre imóvel e endereço? Para mim pareceu a mesma coisa. O detalhe que muda é que o imóvel possui um nome, que poderia ser facilmente uma coluna *nullable* do banco. E se a relação tarefa/endereço é 1 para 1, por quê duas tabelas? Pode armazenar tudo na mesma.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss O imóvel em termos de tabela seria basicamente um nome mesmo, mas está como uma entidade separada porque haveria um cadastro de imóvel onde se colocaria este nome e o seu endereço.<br>
A relação tarefa/endereco seria 1 para 1 mesmo, a ideia de isolar na tabela TarefaEndereco era devido a poder ligar com Endereço diretamente ou com Imóvel.

Comment: Então eu faria duas tabelas apenas: a Tarefa, com uma coluna "idEndereco", como chave estrangeira para Endereço, e a tabela Endereço, que inclui a coluna "nome" do imóvel opcional.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Entendi, sua ideia seria mais simplificada porém funcional. Caso eu tivesse por exemplo a necessidade de armazenar um detalhe adicional do endereço de atendimento para aquela tarefa como por exemplo sala, setor,  onde vai ser atendida a tarefa, seria justificativa para criar a tabela TarefaEndereco por exemplo. Acabei me esquecendo de citar esta possibilidade na descrição inicial do problema.